# Count occurences in Mysql

Tags: mysql, count

Let's say, in given `num_table`, there is a column, in which **only numbers from 1 to 35** are stored.

Code for count nums in last 25rows is:

```
select num, count(*) 
from (select C_1 as num from num_table order by id desc limit 25) n 
group by num 
order by num asc;
```

Result:

```
| num  | count(*) |
|------|----------|
|    2 |        1 |
|    3 |        1 |
|    4 |        1 |
|    5 |        2 |
|   10 |        1 |
|   11 |        1 |
|   12 |        1 |
|   15 |        1 |
|   16 |        2 |
|   17 |        1 |
|   20 |        1 |
|   21 |        1 |
|   22 |        1 |
|   23 |        1 |
|   25 |        1 |
|   28 |        2 |
|   29 |        2 |
|   30 |        1 |
|   32 |        2 |
|------|----------|
```

How to get a result, where nums from 1 to 35 - which occured 0 times within last 25 rows - will be also displayed?

Example of desired result:

```
| num  | count(*) |
|------|----------|
|    1 |        0 |
|    2 |        1 |
|    3 |        1 |
|    4 |        1 |
|    5 |        2 |
|    6 |        0 |
|    7 |        0 |
|    8 |        0 |
|    9 |        0 |
|   10 |        1 |
|  ... |      ... |
|   35 |        0 |
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Use your application language to recognize gaps and fill in 0. Databases search for data that exists and searching for data that doesn't exist doesn't come naturally (note: matching is a bit different and SQL does ok on this).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the quickest way is to make your existing query as sub-query and `LEFT JOIN` your `num_table` with it like :

```
SELECT A.C_1, IFNULL(cnt,0) total_count 
  FROM num_table A 
  LEFT JOIN
      (SELECT num, COUNT(*) cnt
         FROM (SELECT C_1 AS num FROM num_table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 25) n 
               GROUP BY num) B
  ON A.C_1=B.num
GROUP BY A.C_1, cnt
ORDER BY A.C_1 ASC;
```

Here's a fiddle for reference:

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=3ced94d698fd8a55a8ad07a9d3b42f3d

And by the way, the current result you're showing is only 24 rows despite you did `LIMIT 25` in the first sub-query. So in my example fiddle, the result is slightly different.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to solve your problem.

In this solution, first, you need a table with numbers between 1 and 35, but only for the query, so then you can left join (because with a left join you can have also 0 counter values) it with your existent `num_table`.
You can do it like this:

```
WITH RECURSIVE numbers(id) AS (
    SELECT 1 as id
    UNION ALL
    SELECT id+1 FROM numbers WHERE id < 35
)
SELECT numbers.id AS num, count(nt.id) AS total
FROM numbers
LEFT JOIN (SELECT C_1 FROM num_table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 25) nt ON (nt.C_1 = numbers.id)
GROUP BY numbers.id
```